# Error in using calabash-android on linux

Tags: android, calabash

I am getting this error when I tried to run this command :"calabash-android run AndroidPdfViewer_1_0_1.apk"

```
  No test server found for this combination of app and calabash version. Recreating test           server.
  sh: 1: jarsigner: not found
  jarsigner command: jarsigner -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar test_servers/10243e69f88e0cec5718af94160c577f_0.3.8.apk -storepass  -keystore  "/home/avinashkumar_s/.android/debug.keystore" /tmp/d20130125-22494-1fp8e1x/TestServer.apk 
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/calabash-android-0.3.8/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:74:in `sign_apk': Could not sign app (/tmp/d20130125-22494-1fp8e1x/TestServer.apk (RuntimeError)
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/calabash-android-0.3.8/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:28:in `calabash_build'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/tmpdir.rb:129:in `mktmpdir'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/calabash-android-0.3.8/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:10:in `calabash_build'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/calabash-android-0.3.8/bin/calabash-android-run.rb:22:in `calabash_run'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/calabash-android-0.3.8/bin/calabash-android:51
from /usr/local/bin/calabash-android:19:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/calabash-android:19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting Java path in Enviornment Variable.

JAVA_HOME -> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10"